# Java - Add specified number of Dates to a date

Tags: java, date, calendar

There are two date variables (Date1 and Date2) in the format *YYYYMMDD*. What i want is, according to the Date1 I want to set Date2 to the next month day one. For example :

If Date1 = 20111120 then 
I want to set Date2 to 20111201

If Date1 = 20111210 then 
The Date2 should be set to 20120101

No matter the Date1 the Date2 has to be set to next month day one. I cant figure this out how to do it.

Could anyone please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

use `Calendar` to move to the first of next month , `SimpleDateFormat` to parse from String to `Date`

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String date1 = "20111120";
calendar.setTime(format.parse(date1));
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
String date2 = format.format(calendar.getTime()); // date2 is "20111201"
```

Some caveats:

- if you call this more than once, it might be a good idea to instantiate format and calendar only once.
- SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe, so make sure to instantiate one SimpleDateFormat object for each threads (eg. using ThreadLocal)